# Java / C socket, sending multiple variables and receiving it on the client side in differend variables

Tags: java, c, windows, sockets

So I am trying to write a program that uses some form of FTP and other things, this is only early stage and I have encountered some problems with the write method in java and the recv function in C.
I dont really know how to explain it so I attached the code and one example.

```
 public void run() {
        try {


        System.out.println(getName() + " Waiting...");

        synchronized (serverSocket) {
            client = serverSocket.accept();
        }

        System.out.println("Starting Client Connetion with " + getName());

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        dOut = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());



        dOut.write(fileName.getBytes());
        dOut.flush();
        String idk = String.valueOf(fileArray.length);
        dOut.write(idk.getBytes());
        dOut.flush();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        dOut.write(fileArray);
        dOut.flush();
        
        System.out.println("Connection with " + getName() + " has ended");
    } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("CLIENT ERROR");
    } finally {
        clientMap[threadNumber] = false;
        try {
            client.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            dOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

this is the function that handles the clients, I want to be able to send in this order and store in different variables on the client side.

- *The file name*
- *File Size*
- *binary file content*

on the other hand i have the receiving non-blocking socket on windows 10 :

```
void receiveFile(SOCKET ClientSocket) {
char filename_buffer[20];
int fileSize = 0;
unsigned char* receivedFile;
int iResult = 0;
int count = 0;
int total = 0;
////////////////////RECEIVE THE NAME OF THE FILE/////////////////////////////
memset(filename_buffer, '\0', 20);
iResult = recv(ClientSocket, filename_buffer, 20, 0);
if (iResult == -1) {
    printf("Recv Name : error");
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return NULL;
}
printf("File name : %s\nName Length : %d\n", filename_buffer, strlen(filename_buffer));

////////////////////RECEIVE THE SIZE OF THE FILE/////////////////////////////
char size[10];
memset(size, '\0', 10);
iResult = recv(ClientSocket, size, 10, 0);
if (iResult == -1) {
    printf("Recv size : error\n");
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return NULL;
}

fileSize = arrayToInt(size);
if (fileSize == 0) {
    printf("File Size : error");
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return NULL;
}
printf("File size : %d\n", fileSize);

////////////////////RECEIVE THE CONTENT OF THE FILE/////////////////////////////
receivedFile = calloc(fileSize, sizeof(unsigned char));
while ((count = recv(ClientSocket, receivedFile, fileSize, 0)) > 0) {
    total += count;
}

if (count == -1) {
    printf("Recv : error\n");
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return NULL;
}

printf("File content : \n");
for (int i = 0; i < fileSize;i++) {
    printf("%c", receivedFile[i]);
}

printf("\nTotal file bytes received : %d\n", total);

closesocket(ClientSocket);

writeBinaryFile(filename_buffer, receivedFile, fileSize);
printf("Successful write...\n");
```

}

The idea of using 2 different languages is pure didactic, I kinda love C but I need to learn a higher level language.

The problem I have is that when I receive the input from the Java-server on the C-client its all messed up the filename_buffer variable contains some of the size input in it and the size contains some of the file content.

I do not understand how to solve this without using the `Thread.sleep()` method and wait until I receive everything in filename_buffer, wait for the socket buffer to clear and send the file size variable, wait for everything to clear and then send the file content.

One example is this :
having  file[] = "AAAAAA";

```
dOut.write("send_this.jpg".getBytes());
dOut.write(String(file.length).getBytes());
dOut.write(file)  // (as bytes);
```

// The client receives

```
filename_buffer = "send_this.jpg";
size = 6AAAAAA;
receivedFile = "AA..";
```

And using Thread.sleep everything works as expected but I am not so sure its the right way to do this.

Comment: You have a common misunderstanding of how TCP  and `recv` works. Each `recv` cannot be assumed to map to exactly one `send`. You must check how many bytes were received for each `recv` call and your msg format must have framining. By framing I mean that you must be able to tell where each data element starts and ends.

Comment: so the socket buffer just queues up characters , ex : "AAAAAA6send_this.jpg"
and i need ping the size of each input? hope i got it right...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ping the size". But yes, TCP is a continuous stream of data. Each `recv` call can receive any part of the incoming stream - in order of course.

Comment: Consider `dOut.write(idk.getBytes());`, which writes the array length as a string.  How many digits are in the length?  How will the receiving side know that?  If you send `123`, how does the receiving side know whether the sender meant that the array has 123 elements, or the array has 12 elements and the first byte of the first element is 0x33?  For that matter, maybe there’s only one array element and its first two bytes of the first array element are 0x32 x033.

Comment: So i understand now where i wronged my beloved socket, i need to create a way to tell each write-recv apart

Comment: Send the length of each message ahead of the message, as a 16-bit integer.

Comment: Or else use a delimiter - such as \n - to separate elements. Requires scanning the stream received in order to split it up.